uses of the table ccx_auditcountdata_sp and any documentation/information around this table
For the cloud hosted claimcenter application, am looking to understand the uses of the table ccx_auditcountdata_sp and any documentation around this table.
To give a background, any data that is in cloud is send to S3 bucket through Cloud Data Access. The table ccx_auditcountdata_sp provides the count of records for each individual tables in the data model and incrementCount as in any new/updated count on daily basis.Looking for any related documentaion around this.
Could not find any specific documentation related to this.

The suffix of this table indicates that it is an entity added by the SurePath Guidewire content. SurePath is a set of add-ons that are not part of the OOTB product but are added on to a lot of Guidewire applications in order to accomplish a lot of common configurations in a uniform way across implementations.
I would take a look at the SurePath documentation to see what exactly this table is used for. I would also imagine you could look at the ClaimCenter data dictionary for some clues. You may need to enlist the help of a ClaimCenter developer on your team to determine the use of this table. Lastly, in ClaimCenter I would imagine this table is defined by an entity file such as AuditCountData_SP.eti and there may be additional details there. If all the above fails to provide some clarification in terms of documentation or comments in code, you will need to enlist the help of a ClaimCenter developer to investigate how this table is used in the ClaimCenter code.

As Steve mentions, this is part of the "Audit Data for InsuranceSuite" SurePath content available from the Guidewire Marketplace.  The content comes with thorough documentation.  You can access the published content at the following link (login required)  https://marketplace.guidewire.com/s/product/audit-data-for-insurancesuite/01t3n00000TGMNJAA5
